# How to override create button click in the kendo grid

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Spectrum.Model.Bid>()
        .Name("BatchBidGrid")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:460px;" })
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.LotNumber).Title("Lot #").Width(250);
            columns.Bound(p => p.Amount);
            columns.Bound(p => p.BidMessageID).Title("% Increase");
            columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(110);
        })
        .ToolBar(toolbar =>
        {
            toolbar.Create();
            toolbar.Save();
        })
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
        .Pageable()
        .Sortable()
        .Navigatable(n => n.Enabled(true))
        .Events(ev => ev.Edit("onEdit"))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Batch(true)
            .ServerOperation(false)
            .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
            .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.ID))

            .Read("Editing_Read", "Grid")
            .Update("Editing_Update", "Grid")
            .Destroy("Editing_Destroy", "Grid")
        )
        .Events(ev => ev.SaveChanges("submitBatchBid"))
)
```

I want to override the create button click event of this grid I have done the following java script function.

```
$("tr .k-grid-add", "#grid").on("click", function (e) {
            alert("add pressed!");
        })
```

But it is still calling the default grid create function of kendo. Please advice a way to do this.

Comment: Check this [link](http://www.telerik.com/forums/custom-command-button-in-toolbars) if it helps

Comment: $('.k-grid-toolbar button.k-grid-add').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("add pressed!");
    }); can u try this please.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this part:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

at the beginning of your function. This line of code stop the normal code executing and it go ahead with code in your function.

**UPDATE**

Replace the toolbar button:

```
.ToolBar(toolBar => toolBar.Template("<a href=\"\" class=\"k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-myadd\"><span class=\"k-icon k-add\"></span>Add new record</a>"))
```

Then change you javascript with class `k-gri-myadd`:

```
$("tr .k-grid-myadd", "#grid").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("add pressed!");
})
```

Comment: Actually, it will not work, kendo is relative resitant - [here demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/UDECo)

Comment: I tested the code in update in your demo and it works fine for me. Let me know if problems.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to override this by using both:

```
e.preventDefault(); 
e.stopPropagation();
```